# axios.post not sending auth header (but .get does)

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am using axios in my Vue project, and one of the calls to my api involves a `POST`. Both my posts and gets require that the `Authorization` header be set with my token. All get requests work fine, but putting the exact same headers in `axios.post` results in a 403.

Here is my axios code:

```
axios.post('https://my.example.org/myapi/meta?uname=' + uname + '&umetaid=' + post.umeta_id + '&umetavalue=' + post.meta_value, {
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + mytoken }
        })
     .then(function (response) {
       console.log(response)
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error)
     })
```

This always results in a 403 error, and checking my request headers show that the Authorization header is never sent. If I change `axios.post` to `axios.get` above (and add a `GET` method to my api code, in addition to the existing `POST,OPTIONS`), it will execute just fine. I suppose I could leave it this way, but I think it is bad practice to use a `GET` call when one really is performing a `POST`. Is there something I am missing about forming a `POST` request with axios?

Comment: what message are you getting in the console when doing a post?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Axios Post request assumes that the second parameter is data and third parameter is config.

Axios Get request assumes that the second parameter is config while the data is appended in URL.

You are sending data in the url which should be as second parameter(For POST request).

Code Should be:

```
var data = { 
  'uname': uname,
  'umetaid': post.umeta_id,
  'umetavalue': post.meta_value
}
var headers = {
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + mytoken }
}
axios.post('https://my.example.org/myapi/meta',data,headers)
 .then(function (response) {
   console.log(response)
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
   console.log(error)
 })
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Here is the documentation to the order of things when using axios request object with basic auth and other stuff: https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config